# Haskell Stack install package dependency from github

Tags: haskell, github, dependency-management, cabal, haskell-stack

Is it possible to install a version of a package from github using Haskell stack?

e.g. in a `.cabal` or a `stack.yaml` file, how can I point a dependency at a git repo/branch/revision?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**For stack <1.11:**

The [documentation for the `stack.yaml` `packages` section](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#packages) gives examples of referring to more complex package locations.

> ```
> packages:
> - location: .
> - location: dir1/dir2
> - location: https://example.com/foo/bar/baz-0.0.2.tar.gz
> - location: http://github.com/yesodweb/wai/archive/2f8a8e1b771829f4a8a77c0111352ce45a14c30f.zip
> - location:
>     git: git@github.com:commercialhaskell/stack.git
>     commit: 6a86ee32e5b869a877151f74064572225e1a0398
> - location:
>     hg: https://example.com/hg/repo
>     commit: da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
> ```

Then add `extra-dep: true` to the `package` entry just to tell `stack` not to treat the code it pulls in as something you're developing on (e.g., don't load it in GHCi).

Comment: This answer seems out of date. You can specify urls and filepaths under extra-deps

Comment: @Flip could you paste a link to that part of the doc?

Comment: It's on the same page. https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#packages-and-extra-deps There are a lot of examples in this section. From the docs: Extra dependencies, which are packages provided locally on top of the snapshot definition of available packages. These can come from Hackage (or an alternative package index you've defined, see package-indices), an HTTP(S) or local archive, a Git or Mercurial repository, or a local file path.

Answer (score 23):

**New syntax for Stack >1.7.1**

As @Flip commented, the docs at [docs.haskellstack.org](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#packages-and-extra-deps)
clarify the new syntax for your `stack.yaml` is: (note the full commit hash needs to be used)

```
extra-deps:
- github: apolishch/prime_table
  commit: a510622a824af999a809191e8c959b8ea5fa8bdb
- github: apolishch/reactive-banana
  commit: 74bac0f86ed172f95bb6f6a31041992fc161cf79
  subdirs: reactive-banana
```

To be clear: dependencies in your `stack.yaml` make sure that the packages (which are not in Stackage) are available would some `.cabal` file in your project want them, just in case.

You still have to specify the name of the package in `build-depends` in your `.cabal` file to say you actually depend on the package.

Note it doesn't matter what branch the commit is on, and repos can be forks. When a package is in a subdirectory, you can specify it, otherwise it will default to top-level.

**Syntax for Stack >1.6.0**

```
extra-deps:
- github: git@github.com:apolishch/prime_table.git
  commit: a510622a824af999a809191e8c959b8ea5fa8bdb
```

[Edit] I have found that sometimes the syntax from 1.7.1 fails with error message

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.4.3\lib/../mingw/bin\ar.exe: .stack-work\dist\7d103d30\build\objs-10648\libHSpackagename-0.1.0.0-DlGXqyeqb9MDn2z8KhgjVb.a: No such file or directory
```

and I solved that by using the 1.6.0 syntax, even though I was using Stack 1.7.1.
When using Travis, that will fail because Travis can't clone via SSH without your SSH keys of course. But you can still use the https link as

```
extra-deps:
- github: https://github.com/apolishch/prime_table.git
  commit: a510622a824af999a809191e8c959b8ea5fa8bdb
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case i wanted to depend on a fork of pandoc, specifying a precise commit. It worked by adding the following to `stack.yml`:

`extra-deps:
- archive: https://github.com/italia/pandoc/archive/1327c564cccf5dfa387a2956443990d9854c85cd.zip`

This would work with any *branch-like* URL on Git. I found my url by browsing the files at the commit and copying the URL from the "Download ZIP" button.

Note that my branch has a specific version, higher than any version Stack could fetch from the resolver. I pinpoint the version in the Cabal dependencies. If the version on that branch would overlap with one available in the resolver's index, i'm not sure about which one would be picked

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has changed. Now one has to do:

```
packages:
- '.'

extra-deps: 
  - git: https://github.com/haskell/network.git
    commit: 63fb8601003cad1ade959ffcf7be9689fe866421
```